# Wordpress help -Slightly Modded Options framework (SMOF)

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, themes

hello Wordpress and PHP developers I need your help,

friends I am using Slightly Modded Options framework (SMOF) for my new wordpress theme I am trying create Wordpress theme 1st time so I don't know how to access options of this framework.

and also I don't know how to create slider in wordpress could give me suggestion please

How we can access slider slider:

```
$slides = $data['example_slider']; //get the slides array

foreach($slides as $slide) {

    echo $slide['title'];

    echo $slide['url'];

    echo $slide['link'];

    echo $slide['description'];
}
```

here is official links of SMOF you can read:

http://aquagraphite.com/2011/09/slightly-modded-options-framework

http://aquagraphite.com/2011/11/smof-documentation

Answer (score 1):

you have to set global data first: `global $data;` then you can able to fetch SMOF's data.
so your total code would be ---

```
<?php
  global $data;
  $slides = $data['example_slider'];
  foreach($slides as $slide) {
    echo $slide['title'];
    echo $slide['url'];
    echo $slide['link'];
    echo $slide['description'];
}
?>
```

Now you can get all data from your slide (url, image, title, descriptions).
It's ready to create your own slide. Just pick that slider you want.

I give here an example of nivo slider. so your finished code would be--

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    <?php global $data;
    $slides = $data['example_slider'];
    foreach ($slides as $slide) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $slide['link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $slide['url']; ?>" alt="" title="<?php echo $slide['description']; ?>" data-transition="boxRainGrowReverse" /></a>
    <?php }
    ?>  
</div>
```

It's pretty simple huh ?